# Separating Controllers in Laravel4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, controllers, cartalyst-sentry

I apologize for the broadness of this question but I am trying to implement my code in the best possible way and I'm wondering how others have approached this situation. I am building an application using `Laravel4` and it will consist of a `front-end` and `back-end`. I am using `Sentry` for user management also.

Currently I store all of my `controllers` in the `controller` directory and likewise for the `views` however I am wondering If It would be better to store the `controllers` in `subdirectories` and then provide access to these `sub directories` using `sentry`?

In otherwords I'd store all of the `Admin` controllers like so

`app->controllers->admin->nameofcontroller.php`

and the `User` controllers like so

`app->controllers->user->nameofcontroller.php`

Comment: Why not separate different modules of the application in packages (http://laravel.com/docs/packages)?

Comment: That probably isn't necessary.  It is your routes that provide access to your controllers.  A better solution would be to implement some [Sentry based route filters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25383316/controlling-access-to-routes-laravel-and-sentry/25385852#25385852).  Hope this helps.